# I am trying to filter some url from my fetch list by using for loop and if condition in python

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

I am trying to filter some url from my fetch list but its not applying the filter it is giving me the same output from `fetchurl` in `weblinks`
Here is my code

```
weblinks =[]
fetchurl = ['https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=___nkvwpnAg&t=1218', 'https://www.farandwide.com/s/fascinating-facts-every-country-7c1f1a0efdf64979', 'https://www.farandwide.com/s/fascinating-facts-every-country-7c1f1a0efdf64979', 'https://www.farandwide.com/s/fascinating-facts-every-country-7c1f1a0efdf64979', 'https://www.farandwide.com/s/fascinating-facts-every-country-7c1f1a0efdf64979', 'https://www.farandwide.com/s/fascinating-facts-every-country-7c1f1a0efdf64979', 'https://wonderfulwanderings.com/interesting-facts-about-the-netherlands/'] 

 filterlist = ["youtube.com","twitter.com","facebook.com","google.com","tiktok.com"]
        for ur in fetchurl:
                for i in range(len(filterlist)):
                        if filterlist[i] not in ur:
                                weblinks.append(ur)
        print("weblinks url working", weblinks)
```

output

```
weblinks url working ['https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=___nkvwpnAg&t=1218', 'https://www.farandwide.com/s/fascinating-facts-every-country-7c1f1a0efdf64979', 'https://www.farandwide.com/s/fascinating-facts-every-country-7c1f1a0efdf64979', 'https://www.farandwide.com/s/fascinating-facts-every-country-7c1f1a0efdf64979', 'https://www.farandwide.com/s/fascinating-facts-every-country-7c1f1a0efdf64979', 'https://www.farandwide.com/s/fascinating-facts-every-country-7c1f1a0efdf64979', 'https://wonderfulwanderings.com/interesting-facts-about-the-netherlands/']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was that you were adding an element if any of the values from the `filterlist` did not match, but you should if all the values did not match. If at least one match is found, then the inner loop will exit early and the element will not be included in the resulting list. If there is no match, the loop will run in its entirety and `else:` will work, then the element will be included in the final list.

```
weblinks = []
fetchurl = ['https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=___nkvwpnAg&t=1218',
            'https://www.farandwide.com/s/fascinating-facts-every-country-7c1f1a0efdf64979',
            'https://www.farandwide.com/s/fascinating-facts-every-country-7c1f1a0efdf64979',
            'https://www.farandwide.com/s/fascinating-facts-every-country-7c1f1a0efdf64979',
            'https://www.farandwide.com/s/fascinating-facts-every-country-7c1f1a0efdf64979',
            'https://www.farandwide.com/s/fascinating-facts-every-country-7c1f1a0efdf64979',
            'https://wonderfulwanderings.com/interesting-facts-about-the-netherlands/']

filterlist = ["youtube.com", "twitter.com", "facebook.com", "google.com", "tiktok.com"]

for ur in fetchurl:
    for i in filterlist:
        if i in ur:
            break
    else:
        weblinks.append(ur)
print("weblinks url working", *weblinks,sep='\n')
```

```
weblinks url working
https://www.farandwide.com/s/fascinating-facts-every-country-7c1f1a0efdf64979
https://www.farandwide.com/s/fascinating-facts-every-country-7c1f1a0efdf64979
https://www.farandwide.com/s/fascinating-facts-every-country-7c1f1a0efdf64979
https://www.farandwide.com/s/fascinating-facts-every-country-7c1f1a0efdf64979
https://www.farandwide.com/s/fascinating-facts-every-country-7c1f1a0efdf64979
https://wonderfulwanderings.com/interesting-facts-about-the-netherlands/
```